# Access object property on Fastify

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, object, fastify

I tried to fetch the value from the object on Fastify but while I was trying to do so, when I make `GET` request, it keeps loading and network request keep on pending.
Here is how I tried,

I want to access the property of the object (**token**) and assign it to new variable, and then I tried to make `GET` request on browser and it is keep loading and network is `pending`.
Here is my code written on `Fastify` inside the controller section.
**`+ Controller`** section

```
exports.getConversations = async (req, reply) => {
  try {
      var conversationId = this.authentication();
      const { token } = conversationId;
      return token;
  } catch (err) {
    throw boom.boomify(err)
  }
}
```

Here is the object I got from the response of `this.authentication()`:

```
{
    "conversationId": "LMFeL1yqdkfjskkkd2kO5-n",
    "token": "token_value",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Here is the routes which in inside the routes folder under the src directory:

**`+ Route`** section

```
const streamController = require('../controllers/streamController');
const routes = [
  {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/stream/converstations',
    handler: streamController.getConversations
    // schema: documentation.schema
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]

module.exports = routes;
```

Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How did you set up the route? The handler seems right

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I have updated my routes to the question above.

Comment: Could you change the `this.authentication();` to `req.authentication();`? I think it is a binding issue

Comment: Okay sir I will try your approach, however i have use with other way instead of using got, I am using fetch.